# "Variable "$projectId" of required type "ID!" was not provided 400 Bad request

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Apollo Client Query

```
`export const GET_PROJECT = gql`
  query singleProject($projectId: ID!) {
    getProject(projectId: $projectId) {
      _id
      name
      description
      status
    }
  }
;``
```

useQuery

```
const { projectId } = useParams();

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PROJECT, {
    variables: { projectId : projectId },
  });

  const project = data?.project || {};
```

Query works fine in Apollo Sandbox as per below

```
{
  "data": {
    "getProject": {
      "_id": "6595f304af46ebccba110bd0",
      "name": "New prroject",
      "description": "HTML & CSS",
      "status": "planning"
    }
  }
}
```

getting 400 Bad Request and response with an error errors : [{message: "Variable "$projectId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.",…}]
What could be the problem - any help??

Code works on backend and can fetch data in Apollo Sandbox but not able to figure out the reason for required type ID was not provided when I try to run it useQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I over complicated situation - so I simplified the process - I give project detail page route of "project/:id" than I was able to get projectId by using UseParams hooks. Bellow the the code that worked for me - wasn't anything difference.

```
const { id } = useParams();
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PROJECT, {
    variables: { projectId: id },
});
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

1. First check if `projectId` is `undefined`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('projectId=', projectId);
    }, [projectId]);
```

2. The `$projectId` is required, so you can skip executing query when project id is `undefined`.

```
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PROJECT, {
        variables: { projectId : projectId },
        skip: !projectId,
    });
```

Comment: I can access the projectID in console which matches with project id but data comes an empty array which doesnt not allow me to populate the single project details.